# Where does the variable call property come from?

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I am trying to use [Ktor routing](https://ktor.io/servers/features/routing.html#) and I would like to figure out, how the following code works:

```
application.install(Routing) {
        get("/") {
            call.respondText("Hello, World!")
        }
        get("/bye") {
            call.respondText("Good bye, World!")
        }
    }
```

Where does the variable `call` property come from? I looked on https://api.ktor.io/1.4.0/io.ktor.routing/-route/index.html but could not figure out.

I know that the second parameter of `get`:

```
get("/bye") {
                call.respondText("Good bye, World!")
            }
```

expects a lambda. However the `call` variable has to bring into scope. It is not explicit.

Comment: [Does this help](https://ktor.io/servers/calls.html)?

Comment: From the link, `call` seems to be the `context`  within an `ApplicationCall`

Comment: There is a scope provided by the receiver lambda, `call` is implicitly `this.call`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`call` is en extension variable (getter) of `PipelineContext` which as you mentioned is `get` method's second parameter receiver.

```
inline val PipelineContext<*, ApplicationCall>.call: ApplicationCall get() = context
```

Read more on [extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html)